# Addition of a constant potential in the Schrodinger equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, potential-energy, conventions

A really elementary question:

Solutions of the single particle, non-relativistic, time-dependent Schrödinger equation for a spinless particle of mass $m$ alone in space, with no forces acting on it, with the potential function $V(r,t) = 0$, include all constant frequency, wavelength, and amplitude plane wave functions $\Psi$. Because the similar Schrödinger equation with any constant potential $V(r,t) = P$ describes the same physical situation, since it is only differences in potential that have any physical significance, the Schrödinger equation with the potential $V(r,t) = P$, for any real $P \neq 0$, which also describes a situation with no forces on the particle, should also have as solutions all the ones described above for the Schrödinger equation with $V(r,t) = 0$, but it doesn't.

What is the explanation?

The following reply to Stratiev is too long for a comment, so I am including it here.

If a function $ψ′(x,t) = kψ(x,t)$, for $k$ any complex **constant**, then $ψ′$ satisfies a given linear partial differential equation, such as the Schrodinger equation, if and only if $ψ$ satisfies that equation. If the wavefunction $ψ′$ that you suggested would satisfy the Schrodinger equation with some non-zero potential $P$ differed by a constant phase factor $k$, which would be a complex number of norm 1, from a solution $ψ$ of the Schrodinger equation with zero $P$, then $ψ$ would also satisfy the same Schrodinger equation for the non-zero $P$ as $ψ′$ satisfied. **However**, your $ψ′$ for the non-zero $P$ situation differed from the ψ for the zero P by a factor of exp(iPt/(2 π h), which is not a constant phase factor, since it is a non-constant function of t.

[If you will review your differential equations theory, you will see that global
differences in phase which don't affect what linear differential equations a
function satisfies must be differences by a factor of a complex **number**,  not the value of a function which varies with one of the variables of the differential equation.]

Answer (score 1):

If you solve the time-independent Schrödinger equation first, you'd see that the solutions you get have their energy eigenvalues shifted by a constant $P$. Solving for the time dependence in the eigenstates, you'd get solutions whose frequencies $\omega'_n$ are also shifted by a constant $\omega'_n = \omega_n +\frac{P}{\hbar}$, where $\omega_n$ are the frequencies of the oscillator with $V(r,t)=0$. As is well known, global phases in the wave function are not measurable, so the differences in these phases don't matter.

However, one can think of linear combinations of Hamiltonian eigenstates $\Psi =\sum_{i} e^{i \omega_n t} | n \rangle $. Again, since every eigenvalue is shifted by the same amount, we have $$\Psi' = \sum_n e^{i (\omega_n+\frac{P}{\hbar} t)} |n\rangle=e^{i \frac{P}{\hbar} t} \sum_{i} e^{i \omega'_n t} | n \rangle= e^{i \frac{P}{\hbar} t} \Psi, $$ which is a global shift in phase, which is unobservable. Hence the solutions of the time-dependent Schrödinger equation for a potential shifted by a constant are physically the same, despite differing at first sight.

The above argument can be applied to any time-independent Hamiltonian, not just the free particle case.

Comment: I believe you mean $\omega '_n = \omega_n + P/ \hbar$

Comment: @BillN Yes, I was being sloppy, I'll fix it.

Comment: Reply to Stratiev,

Comment: To Stratiey: The total energy is shifted by P, but the kinetic energy KE remains the same, so the solutions for the shifted P, which have the same velocity as those for the unshifted P, and the same mass m, have a plane-wave wave function with the same frequency and wavelength as the unshifted solution, since PW solutions of the form exp[i(kx-wt)] are determined by the k, w,  and m,which determine their velocity (really speed) and so KE. This wave function, however, doesn't satisfy the SE with the shifted P.

Comment: @MichaelFox You are forgetting that in order for $e^{i(kx - \omega t)}$ to be a solution, there is a relation between $k$ and $\omega$ that needs to be satisfied. In the $P=0$ case, that relation is roughly $\omega \sim k^2$ (I'm omitting units and masses here but you can figure out the exact relation). In the case of $P\neq0$, the relation is more like $\omega \sim k^2 + \frac{P}{\hbar}$. Which is again the same shift in phase that I mentioned in my answer. Let me know if this is still unclear and I can edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The solutions aren't the same. In general, the time-independent Schrödinger equation reads
$$\left[\frac{-\hbar^2}{2m}\nabla^2 +V(\vec{r})\right]\psi(\vec{r})=E\psi(\vec{r})$$
I have removed the time dependance of the potential because it is not needed if it is null everywhere or constant. This equation is normally re-written in the form
$$\nabla^2\psi(\vec{r})+k^2\psi(\vec{r})=0$$
where $k^2=\frac{2m(E-V(\vec{r}))}{\hbar^2}$ so the solutions to this equation will vary depending on the value of $V(\vec{r})$. However, as explained in the above answer, adding a **constant potential** will just phase shift the solution.